# MySQL. Procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I am pretty new to MySQL and I have a question, hoping I'll find the answer here. I have a list of projects my college teacher gave me to work on and do all of them but I'm hitting a new term "procedure". I tried to research it but I have failed to find a satisfying answer and I know you can help me.

Basically I have an exercise, the query is fine, it works fine but I was told it needs to be a procedure. 
Now.. my questions are:

1. What is a procedure?
2. When am I to use a procedure?
3. How can I use a procedure?

As I said above, I tried finding some proper documentation/tutorials where procedures are explained but I failed to do so, so I am hoping there is someone here that can explain it to me, I understand better if someone else is explaining it to me, rather than reading the documentation.

Thank you and here is the query in question, the query that has to be a procedure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT producator, AVG(pret) AS medie 
FROM vehicul v
JOIN proprietate p
ON v.id_vehicul = p.nr_vehicul
WHERE producator = 'Ford';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be a exersice for you and not for us.
But you can look here for an explaination of procedures in mssql:
http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/news/1052737/Why-use-stored-procedures

http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/storedprocedure.htm

Comment: It's an exercise for me, of course. But I provided the query so you can explain the procedures on my query. 
However, the links you gave me, provide the answer to all the questions I've asked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A procedure is like a method in other programming languages. It enables you to regroup queries and apply them by a simple call.

You can find information about procedures in the mysql documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: I found that documentation as well, but "A procedure is like a method in other programming languages." This answers my first two questions.

Answer (score 1):

According to my opinion this query doesn't need to become a procedure. Here are the link from where you can refer to procedure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782.aspx

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same and the query is all fine.. but the question wants it to be a procedure, I guess it's a part of my training.. to get used to procedures.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this query to be convertred into procedure, then you can try somnthing like this:-

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  proc_name();

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name()
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT producator, AVG(pret) AS medie 
    FROM vehicul v
    JOIN proprietate p
    ON v.id_vehicul = p.nr_vehicul
    WHERE producator = 'Ford';
END $$
DELIMITER;
```